# Update OpenGL cube after translation and scale?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a class that should draw a cube.

It draws my cube nicely in the main, but I create it with default x,y,z values in order to have it in the center of the screen by default. I would like to translate and scale the cube after this is drawn by calling `build`, but I'm clearly missing something as my solution doesn't work for the translation and scale.

My code, at the moment, is the following:

**build.h**

```
class build
{
public:
    enum shape { CUBE }; //this is to have different 3D objects drawn by this class

    build(shape myShape);
    ~build();

    void set_pos(vec2 new_pos);
    vec3 get_pos();
    void change_size(GLfloat new_side);
    GLfloat get_size();
    void move(vec3 &move_vec);

private:
    void draw_cube();
    shape myShape= CUBE;
    vec3 pos = vec3(/* pos here */);
    GLfloat side = 5.0f;
};
```

**build.cpp**

```
build::build(shape my_shape)
{
    myShape = my_shape;

    switch (myShape ) {
    case CUBE:
        draw_cube()
        break;
    default:
        draw_cube()
        break;
    }
}

build::~build()
{
}

void build::draw_cube()
{       
    GLfloat verts[] =
    {
        pos.x, pos.y + side, pos.z

        /* Rest of the vertices here */
    };

    GLfloat col[] =
    {
        //colours
    };

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glColor3f(col[0], col[2], col[2]);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, verts);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 24);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}

void build::set_pos(vec2 new_pos)
{    
    glTranslatef(new_pos.x, new_pos.y, -250);
}

vec3 build::get_pos()
{
    return vec3(pos);
}

void build::change_size(GLfloat new_side)
{
    side = new_side;
}

GLfloat build::get_size()
{
    return GLfloat(side);
}

void build::move(vec3 &move_vec)
{
    pos += move_vec;
}
```

Then I call in my `main.cpp`

```
glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, 500);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glLoadIdentity();

//This is to rotate the cube by pressing key, and it works
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, -250);
glRotatef(rotationX, 1, 0, 0);
glRotatef(rotationY, 0, 1, 0);
glTranslatef(-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, -SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, 250);

build *cube = new build(build::CUBE);

//My problem is here, since the cube is drawn at the origin but doesn't move if I call move() method
cube->move(vec3(100.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

glPopMatrix();

glfwSwapBuffers(window);
glfwPollEvents();
```

I would like to keep this code structure, as I want to draw different 3D objects by calling `build::OBJECTTYPE`, but I have to be able to get and set position and size of my objects as I will need it later in the code.

Comment: That's not possible. You can't modify the transformation after it has been drawn. At the moment of the draw-call all information has to be present.

Comment: Many pitfall here, we need something minimal but complete. From a frist reading, I found strange: the usage of glOrtho (are you sure you want it? that can hide translation on z), the cube is allocated in the render function (everytime new values?), move should be applied using "gl-functions" not changing the vertex of your object (you shouldn't do it), 100.0f as offset...how much that is compared to your cube size?..my 2 cents, Ste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do the "draw" call (`build::draw_cube`) in the constructor of the class `build`.
The line

```
build *cube = new build(build::CUBE);
```

always creates a new cube and draws it. After that you move the cube:

```
cube->move(vec3(100.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
```

but you never draw the moved cube, because in the next cycle you create a new cube at the initial position.

First you should implement a default constructor in the class `build`:

```
build::build() {}
```

Set the initial position, before you draw the cube:

```
build cube;
cube.move( vec3(100.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) );
cube.draw_cube();
```

Of course you can manipulate the `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix, instead of creating meshes with different vertices:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glPushMatrix();

glTranslatef(100.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

glTranslatef(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, -250);
glRotatef(rotationX, 1, 0, 0);
glRotatef(rotationY, 0, 1, 0);
glTranslatef(-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, -SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, 250);

build cube;
cube.draw_cube();

glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `cube->move(..)`, use `glTranslatef(pos1,pos2,pos3)`, passing `posX` arguments too just like you are passing `rotationX`, `rotationY` from main, which will translate the cube. Also, you might try calling this function just after `glPushMatrix()` if you don't get your desired result.